# Can you make imines from Formaldehyde or Acetaldehyde?

Tags: synthesis

Title says it all. Wondering if imine formation would work with an aldehyde, even better would be formaldehyde.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does. They are reactive species, methylene imines particularly are easily hydrolysed back to amine + aldehyde.

They are the basis of reductive methylation/alkylation of primary amines where reaction with alkyl halides, especially reactive ones such as MeI risks dialkylation. More details here [reductive alkylation](https://www.organic-chemistry.org/synthesis/C1N/amines/reductiveamination.shtm)

Comment: Thank you, I figured it would but couldn't wanted to make sure before I used it in a presentation. Also, I was wondering about alkylation of ammines for a while now!

Comment: @ronnie   Please accept the answer if you are happy with it